# normal.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I always get this error

> normal.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of
>   null

Here the html code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <form >
            <input class="button btn-red" type="button" name="btn" value="random" onclick="myFunction()">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <a id "test">...</a>
            <p>Some other text...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

here the javascript code:

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Its working";}
```

Comment: You're missing assignment operator, it should be: `id="test"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `<a id "test">...</a>` to `<a id="test">...</a>`

Comment: thanks a lot i cant believe that i dont saw that for 3 hours

Comment: Your welcome my friend. I'm glad the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have a syntax error on your html code

It should be:

```
<a id="test"></a>
```

Instead of:

```
<a "test"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an equal to sign immediately after your the "id" attribute in your HTML.
It should look like;

`<a id="test">...</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy paste this in your code and Solved Issue:-

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <form >
        <input class="button btn-red" type="button" name="btn" value="random" onclick="myFunction()">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <a id="test">...</a>
        <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Its working";}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code misses equal to sign where you are assigning an anchor tag with an Id = test.

```
<a id="test">...</a>
```